# Module installation Problem in Pypy Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, list, cmd, module

I am trying to install packages to my pypy module however it keeps giving me this error. I am interested in installing the pandas module however giving me this error. I am on a windows 10 setup. This is the cmd output of the error. The pypy module is installed in the correct full path and all but its giving me errors when `pypy3 -m pip install numpy` or `pypy3 -m pip install pandas`. Anything helps.

```
C:\Users\maste>pypy3 -m pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.19.4.zip (7.3 MB)
|                      | 7.3 MB 6.4 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\pypy3.exe' 'C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuja3njcr'
         cwd: C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-enqvkl9m\numpy_8a18699305b847b3837072be339821a5
    Complete output (191 lines):
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Found executable C:\cygwin64\bin\DF.exe
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RarEXa8572.21538\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      FOUND:
        language = c

    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win32-3.7
    creating build\src.win32-3.7\numpy
    creating build\src.win32-3.7\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-enqvkl9m\numpy_8a18699305b847b3837072be339821a5\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-enqvkl9m\numpy_8a18699305b847b3837072be339821a5\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-enqvkl9m\numpy_8a18699305b847b3837072be339821a5\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-enqvkl9m\numpy_8a18699305b847b3837072be339821a5\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-enqvkl9m\numpy_8a18699305b847b3837072be339821a5\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\pypy3.exe' 'C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\RarEXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuja3njcr' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you using  `pypy3`???

just use `pip install numpy` , `pip install pandas` ... and so one.

I strongly recommend you uninstall python and all your packages and then reinstall them correctly, either from [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) or [python.org](https://www.python.org/), and then use the commands from [PyPi.org](https://pypi.org/), for example for numpy, use [this](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/).

Comment: Oh i had already installed pandas and numpy in python. i thought i was supposed to install it for pypy.